# real time drawing - what to use

Tags: graphics, drawing

Hello
I want to do a small web based game in which there will be 2 users and one of them needs to draw something in canvas and the second one needs to guess what is that. Both of the sides needs to see the process of drawing... very simple game. What should I use to make it? Javascript, Java, jQuery, or maybe something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to go with jQuery + some canvas plugin (like jCanvas) on the client side and anything you want (PHP/Java/C#/etc) on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I found this blogpost about Silverlight + Wcf Polling Duplex

this might be something useful?

[blogpostlink](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2009/11/silverlight-wcf-duplex-services.html)